# how to let a superuser fill some forms for other users

Tags: django

I want to create a Django app that has two types of users. A regular user can register and fill in some contact and personal info on their profile page. The staff users have the ability to edit or add some additional info for the regular users. To be more specific, they need to fill a scientific survey for every user.
Firstly, I need a page that shows all the users sorted by those who have the survey object and those who don't, and finally, by clicking on their name, the staff user gets redirected to the survey form related to that specific user. Do you guys have any suggestions on how am I supposed to do this?
I created a model like this:

```
class ScientificSurvey(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    info1 = models.CharField(max_length=24, choices=SURVEY_CHOICES)
    info2 = models.CharField(max_length=24, choices=SURVEY_CHOICES)
    info3 = models.CharField(max_length=24, choices=SURVEY_CHOICES)
    info4 = models.CharField(max_length=24, choices=SURVEY_CHOICES)
    info5 = models.CharField(max_length=24, choices=SURVEY_CHOICES)
```

Users themselves cannot access this model and only the staff user is allowed to create or edit one for the users. I couldnt find anything on the web that could help me.

Comment: What did you try so far? You'll probably need to split a view and related template to manage and display your form according to the logged user

Comment: nothing really but I thought I could user generic views and CreateView to able to fill the forms. But how should I do it? the request.user is not as same as the surveyInfo.user

Comment: @Christophe gave you a good idea on how to start your project, so far you did not try much and unfortunately you learn by doing. 
We can help you if you are stuck on a more specific question, otherwise I would recommend to follow the Django tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: Starting with generic views (following the doc) can be a good approach: you define a first form, then a second one, finally you build a complete view and related template. For your split, you might probably test `request.user.is_superuser` unless you define your own user's model (depending on your application)